# Android MvvmCross - Bind to static constant

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Working on an Android app using MvvmCross with a shared core library, I was wondering if there is a possibility to bind to static constants which are located outside the viewmodel to a property in the view. For example bind the background color of the tabbar to the TabBar field in the Colors class.

```
public static class Colors
{
    public static readonly MvxColor MainGray = new MvxColor(0xff2D3030);
    public static MvxColor TabBar => MainGray;
}
```

If this is not possible, are there any best practises which I can take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't do exactly what you want to, there are a few other different approaches you could take. The easiest way would be to store a reference to the colour in a property on your ViewModel. So you might do:

```
public MvxColor BackgroundColor => Colors.MainGray;
```

You're then free to bind any colour to that property I've just created.

Another option is making your Colors class instanced instead of static. You could then store an instance of that class in a property in your ViewModel and bind to its properties. For instance if you had:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    CoreColors = new Colors();
}

public Colors CoreColors;
```

Then you could bind your BackgroundColor to CoreColors.MainGray

There are lots of other ways to do this but with your current setup, either of these ways would work just fine! However it is worth keeping in ming that if you want to update a colour and have it update the binding, you'll need to make sure you have something on the property notifying the binding that it needs to update. If you take on my second example, this is how I'd set up your Colors class to support this:

```
public class Colors : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static MvxColor MainGray => new MvxColor(0xff2D3030);

    private MvxColor _tabBar = MainGray;
    public MvxColor TabBar
    {
        get { return _tabBar; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _tabBar, value); }
    }
}
```

Now if you want bind to TabBar, the TabBar will be MainGray until you set the TabBar colour to something else, and the UI should update the colour.